# Clang++ works via command line, but not on SublimeText via SublimeClang (Win8x64)

Tags: mingw, clang, sublimetext2

Using MinGW 4.7.0, MSYS-compiled Clang 3.2.

I got MinGW via the automatic installer/downloader, and built Clang following these instructions: http://bencode.net/clangonwindows

---

Calling "g++ --version" on PowerShell returns: `enter code here`

Calling "clang -v" on PowerShell returns: `clang version 3.2 (trunk 167353)
Target: i686-pc-mingw32
Thread model: posix`

---

I created a little test file to check if clang was working, "test.cpp":

```
#include <iostream>

class clangIsCool
{
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
};

int main() 
{
    clangIsCool *c; 
    std::cout << c->x * 10;

    return 0;
}
```

Calling "clang++ test.cpp" gives me no errors.

---

I then got SublimeClang for SublimeText2 using Package Control.

SublimeClang can be found here: https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang

Loading "test.cpp" in SublimeText2 and trying to compile gives me these errors:

```
C:/MinGW/include\wctype.h:99,33 - Error - definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\cwchar:145,11 - Error - no member named 'fgetws' in the global namespace
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\cwchar:147,11 - Error - no member named 'fputws' in the global namespace
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\cwchar:151,11 - Error - no member named 'getwc' in the global namespace
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\cwchar:152,11 - Error - no member named 'getwchar' in the global namespace
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\cwchar:157,11 - Error - no member named 'putwc' in the global namespace
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\cwchar:158,11 - Error - no member named 'putwchar' in the global namespace
C:/MinGW/include\ctype.h:112,33 - Error - redefinition of '_ctype'
C:/MinGW/include\ctype.h:112,33 - Error - definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer
C:/MinGW/include\ctype.h:117,34 - Error - redefinition of '_pctype_dll'
```

I checked SublimeClang's settings, and this is the options clang is using:

```
"options":
[
    "-isystem", "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/",
    "-isystem", "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1",
    "-F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/",
    "-isystem", "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.0\\include",
    "-isystem", "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.0\\include\\c++",
    "-isystem", "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.0\\include\\c++\\mingw32",
    "-isystem", "C:\\MinGW\\include",
    "-Wall"
],
```

I tried messing around with the include paths (even though they look correct to me as they are), but the errors still remain.

Is there any other path I should include in SublimeClang's options?

Is there a way to see what paths clang uses by default (because it works from the command line), so that I can compare them to the one SublimeClang is defaulted to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting the same errors from `#include <iostream>`, and I was able to stop them by defining `__GNUC__=4`, `__GNUC_MINOR__=7` (obviously, this is for GCC 4.7) and  `__MSVCRT__=1`.

Unfortunately,  `#include <vector>` gets me a whole bunch of other errors:

```
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\bits/alloc_traits.h:56,35 - Error - in-class initializer for static data member is not a constant expression
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\bits/alloc_traits.h:86,24 - Error - type 'int' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\ext/alloc_traits.h:105,11 - Error - using declaration refers into '_Base_type::', which is not a base class of '__alloc_traits<int>'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\ext/alloc_traits.h:106,11 - Error - using declaration refers into '_Base_type::', which is not a base class of '__alloc_traits<int>'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\ext/alloc_traits.h:107,11 - Error - using declaration refers into '_Base_type::', which is not a base class of '__alloc_traits<int>'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\ext/alloc_traits.h:108,11 - Error - using declaration refers into '_Base_type::', which is not a base class of '__alloc_traits<int>'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\ext/alloc_traits.h:109,11 - Error - using declaration refers into '_Base_type::', which is not a base class of '__alloc_traits<int>'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\bits/stl_vector.h:81,16 - Error - base specifier must name a class
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\bits/stl_vector.h:235,13 - Error - using declaration refers into '_Base::', which is not a base class of 'vector<int, std::allocator<int> >'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\bits/stl_vector.h:236,13 - Error - using declaration refers into '_Base::', which is not a base class of 'vector<int, std::allocator<int> >'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\bits/stl_vector.h:237,13 - Error - using declaration refers into '_Base::', which is not a base class of 'vector<int, std::allocator<int> >'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\bits/stl_vector.h:238,13 - Error - using declaration refers into '_Base::', which is not a base class of 'vector<int, std::allocator<int> >'
C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/include/c++\bits/stl_vector.h:527,13 - Error - using declaration refers into '_Base::', which is not a base class of 'vector<int, std::allocator<int> >'
```

I can only assume that this is also due to more missing or wrong defines. However, I tried adding every define that g++ provides (http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/What_are_the_default_defines_in_my_Gnu_compiler?) but it seemed to have no effect (other than adding a huge list of macro redefined warnings).

My SublimeClang project settings are as follows (the default settings are untouched):

```
"sublimeclang_additional_language_options":
{
  "c++" : ["-std=c++11"]
},

"sublimeclang_options":
[
  "-D__GNUC__=4",
  "-D__GNUC_MINOR__=7",
  "-D__MSVCRT__=1",
  "-IC:\\project-specific-source",
  "-IC:\\project-specific-library\\include",
  "-isystem", "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.0\\include",
  "-isystem", "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.0\\include\\c++",
  "-isystem", "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.7.0\\include\\c++\\mingw32",
  "-isystem", "C:\\MinGW\\include",
  "-Wall",
  "-ferror-limit=0"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same errors, it was because llvm was built with a different version of mingw+gcc. I tried building clang myself but it didn't help.
Today I solved this by installing mingw+gcc from here:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-dw2-4.6-release/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-dw2-4.6.3-2-release-win32_rubenvb.7z/download
```

and clang from here:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/clang-3.2-release/i686-w64-mingw32-clang-3.2-release-win32_rubenvb.7z/download
```

Put everything in the same folder so that bot g++.exe and clang++.exe are in the same bin folder and put that bin folder in your PATH.

This is my sublimeclang configuration now:

```
{
    "additional_language_options":
    {
        "c++" : ["-std=c++11",
                 "-ID:\\Apps\\mingw32-gcc-dw2-4.6.3-2-clang-3.2-win32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include"]
    },

    "options":
    [
        "-g",
        "-O2",
        "-Wall",
        "-Wextra"
    ],

    "debug_options": false,

    "dont_prepend_clang_includes": true,

    "analyzer_commandline":
    [
        "clang.exe",
        "--analyze",
        "-o",
        "-"
    ]
}
```

The `-I` part is required because of `dont_prepend_clang_includes`.